# When does the CPU benefit of having an Hibernate 2nd level cache outweigh the initial hit

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

When does the CPU benefit of having an object added to Hibernate 2nd level object cache outweigh the initial hit.

I am currently using Hibernate without 2nd level cache. This is for an application that processes music files ([www.jthink.net/songkong](http://www.jthink.net/songkong)) and it uses Hibernate so it can scale with more data, i.e it can process 100,000 songs with little more memory than 1000 songs. Once the songs have been processed then those songs are of no interest (unless the user runs Undo)

As I understand it if I enable 2nd level cache (for my song class) then the initial write of the song to cache will use more cpu then if just writing to database, and additional modifications to the song object will also require more cpu resource. But subsequent retrieval of the song from Ehcache will require less resource then retrieving it from database.

My songs are processed folder by folder and go through a number of stages (on different Executors), when they are queued on the next Executor we just pass the song ids as parameters otherwise, it would use a lot of heap memory storing the Song objects themselves. So when a particular task is actually run on an Executor the first thing it does is retrieve the songs for those ids.

So there are no particular song ids that are retrieved 1000s of times, but every song is typically written to between 1 and 4 times and retrieves 10 times. So if we had a quite small cache (because I want to keep heap memory under close control) I would expect the first few folders to be processed to have their songs added to the cache, then as they complete songs from new folders would take their place in the cache.

But my question is, is it worth it?

As a rule of thumb does 10 retrievals versus 1-4 writes makes sense of using 2nd level cache, or is only useful if the ratio is more like 100:1?

Comment: im debating within, if this is an appropriate Q for SO.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog why would it not be ?

Comment: Cause this is about how software affects hardware. In which case it belongs maybe at SuperUser for example. This is not a programmatical question thus I believe it doesnt belong to SO. So it should be closed or moved to the appropriate SE site.

Comment: No its a software question , working out the best algorithm. All software effects hardware but its not a question about hardware.

Comment: You sure? "When does the CPU benefit " If its a software question then its incomplete because you dont show any of the code you have tried so far, and yet should be closed as being too broad.....

Comment: You are misrepresenting, that sentence simply means whats the threshold whereby the time saving from having in cache outweighs the hit of writing changes to cache. The question is algorithmic, I know how to write the code but not if it make sense to do so.

Comment: You can not calculate the Algorithmic complexity of using the Second Level cache against not using it. Do not forget that the DB uses the CPU as well, so even a real DB call will end up using the CPU by the DB and if the DB is on other physical server than your tread will be blocked until you get the response. So even 2:1 can be useful if there is latency problem with your DB. Just remember that cache is used to reduce the latency and yes overall it can even reduce the CPU usage. So you should analyze it on your environment and see if it makes sense or not.

Comment: @Babl Datbase is on same machine and virtualmachine (java h2 db) I am trying things out but results are confusing so just trying to get a general rule.

Comment: @PaulTaylor there is no general rule, everything depends on your hardware on your network on your application and your goals. But as I said main goal of using the cache should be reducing the latency. Use some profiler and see where is the slow down, is it in your app in the cache or somewhere else. But in most cases if you are updating the data after each 4 reads I do not think it makes sense to cache the results unless you need the data super fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real answer is: **Just benchmark it.**

Writing to heap cache isn't that costly. So yes, even retrieving once from the cache will make it faster then boing back to the database.

Then, a cache does mostly two things on top of a HashMap. It evicts and expires.

Eviction means that you set some maximum size to the cache. When this is reached, the cache will evict the "oldest" entry to add a new one. There are multiple definitions for oldest. Ehcache does a sampling over a set of entries and kicks out the entry that wasn't accessed for the longest time in the sample.

Expiration means that a given entry will be considered stale at some point. For instance, you want to keep an entry 1 hour before refreshing the entry with the latest one in the database. When you get an entry, Ehcache first looks if the entry is expired. If it is, it will return null and remove the entry from the cache. It means that an expired entry will stay in the cache until you try to access it.

In your case, you will want to load the entry once. Then have it in cache. Use it and finally remove it to save memory. If you have a final step where you know you won't need the entry anymore, just remove it there.

If you don't, you will have to rely on eviction. Because the eviction algorithm will remove expired entries first (why removing a perfectly valid entry if you can remove expired one?).

You should calculate how many time an entry should stay in cache to go through all the Executors. This will be your expiry time (TTL). Then you size your cache more or less to `NB_EXECUTORS * NB_STEPS`. It will then be the size of the currently in used songs. When adding a new song, the cache will need to evict an old entry. In most cases, this entry will be expired so no harm done.

To prevent eviction (which can be costly when not finding an expired entry), you can code a background routine that gets entries. It will trigger expiration. But again, don't do that before being sure, using a benchmark, that it is actually faster.

Finally, you might want to cache a song directly instead of using Hibernate level 2. Because it will require less operation to get the song. Also, when writing an entry that was in second-level cache, Hibernate tend to evict from the cache. Make sure you configure it to **NOT** do that.

A note about modification. By default Ehcache on-heap cache (and only on-heap cache) is per reference. So if you retrieve a Song object from the cache and then modify it, the entry in cache is modified as well since it's actually the one and only instance.

However, that's not how Hibernate second level cache works. They will keep in cache some kind of database row. This will be converted to the Song and returned to you.

When you save the Song to database, Hibernate will evict it from the cache as I was saying above (but you might ask for a cache update in the configuration, I'm not sure about that).

That's why I think you should cache directly instead of using second-level cache. However, watch out because you get an object loaded by Hibernate. You need to detach it from Hibernate before putting it in cache. And then attach it in the new executor. Otherwise, if you have collections for instance, strange things can happen.

Now, assuming you want to update the cache and database every time. You have two ways to do it.

With Cache-aside, you will update the DB then update the cache.

With Cache-through, you will update the cache which will take care (atomitacally) of updating the DB. Cache-through is a little more involved since you need to provide a `CacheLoaderWriter` implementation. But it makes sure the cache and database are always in sync.

Comment: Thankyou Im not clear what you mean by cache-through pattern, and why write would evict from cache. Also why do I need to add an evict timer rather than just use  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" ?

Comment: See here for the patterns (cache-through is a read-write through) http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.6/caching-patterns.html. Eviction occurs when the cache is full and you try to add another entry. Then, expiration occurs when accessing an entry. So you can have a cache filled with expired entries but you won't know until you try to access them.

Comment: sorry Henri Im being dumb I still dont get what you are getting at. As I see it you add an element to the cache, and you carry on adding things to cache, once cache is full then when you try to add to cache it will have to remove the oldest entry first. I dont get that cache would have entries that have expired, i.e contain entries that ar ein cache but not allowed to access them because expired, if expired wont they be replaced with something else ?

Comment: Ok. I wasn't clear at all now that I re-read myself. I've removed the part about cache-aside/cache-through. It was irrelevant in your case. I got lost in overthinking However, I will add a note about Hibernate second-level cache. You might not want to use it.

Comment: Hi Ive awrded you bounty but still couple of things not quite clear on. Song can change as it goes through steps, so whenever I retrieve from cache I want to ensure this represents the latest version, not clear if ths happens automtically or not based on what yo say about considering item stale. Then in your last line you say wehn writing an entry in cache it gets evicted from cache, I assumed it would get replaced with new version so how do ci configure accordingly.

Comment: Let me add some more details :-) Do you want to save it to database at every step as well?

Comment: it has to be saved at every step it has been modified at since I dont ever want to rely on data being in cache, cache is just an improvement for performance

Comment: Ok. Good. You shouldn't. You are right. It means you will want to save and update the cache.